# Visual studio 2022: High CPU Usage of ServiceHub.Host.dotnet.x64.exe

Tags: cpu-usage, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know why ServiceHub.Host.dotnet.x64.exe would be using so much CPU?

Almost each time I start coding in VS2022 CPU usage goes up...

[image]

thx
Frederik

Comment: also servicehub.roslyncodeanalysisservice.exe likes to use a lot op CPU...